# Cytoscape.js - create circular nodes with size

Tags: cytoscape.js

In cytoscape I'd like to create nodes that are circular, with the diameter depending on the node label (the label is centered in the node). I've set the following:

```
style: {
    'shape': 'ellipse',
    'width': 'label'
}
```

How do I get the height to depend on the width value? Setting 'height': 'label' sets the height to the height of the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use a fixed-width font, then @BeerBaron's answer is best.

Alternatively, use the stylesheet you have in the OP:

```
style: {
  'shape': 'ellipse',
  'width': 'label',
  'height': 'data(height)'
}
```

Update node heights as a step post-init, e.g.

```
cy.nodes().forEach(function( n ){ n.data('height', n.width()); });
```

You should probably preset `data.height` for each node to some default value at init to ease debugging (e.g. when you add new nodes later).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on label lenght and font, you can set width and height in the javascript part that is appending nodes to the graph, and leave the rest of the style to the initialization of the engine.

For example:

```
cy.add({
        group: 'nodes',
        style: {
            height: (10*label.lenght),
            width: (10*label.lenght),
        }
    })
```